# How to hide console window while opening hidden COM object using C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

I am new to C++ so please be gentle. So i created a small C++ script which will be a part of a larger program. It creates an invisible window and navigates to home. While that part is done, it always creates a console window when it finishes execution and then in less than a second it vanishes. What do i need to change in order to make the program work in a way that the console window won't open ?

Comment: The code you showed is for a console app (`main()` entry point), so of course a Console window will appear when it is run. Make a GUI app (`WinMain()` entry point) instead, and just omit the GUI portion. That being said, why are you creating an invisible IE browser to begin with?  Why are you performing *non-visual* work with a *visual* control? For non-visual work, consider using an HTTP library instead, like WinInet/WinHTTP.  Or at least a [headless-browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) if you need HTML parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of compiling as a console application, compile as a windows desktop project.  Then convert `main` to be `WinMain`

Comment: I copy pasted the above code and replaced the code VS auto-generated in a new windows desktop project. I then converted main to WinMain. It doesnt compile and gives 43 Errors.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @Shah999 "*It doesnt compile and gives 43 Errors.*" - then you did something wrong in the conversion, but we can't see what you did.  Please show the new code.